# Reading Fractions in a txt file java

Tags: java, split, readfile

I've been trawling the internet for help with this, but i can't find it so i'm resorting to posting.

I have a txt file that is formatted like this

1/2 0 1/6
6/11 1/6 2/10

I need to read each of these seperate Fractions and input the numerator and denominator in a function called BigFraction(num, denom).

I call the reader and output it as a string.
Then i split on the whitespaces to get the individual fractions as strings
input them into my helper method, strToBF,
which splits on the forwardslash and inputs the numerator and denominator.

but its not working, any help would be greatly appreciated

my main method

```
            String file = fileToString(fileName);
    file.replaceAll("(.*)\\/(.*)", "a");
    String[] splitFile = file.split(" ");

    BigFraction conditionA = stringToBF(splitFile[0]);
    BigFraction c1A = stringToBF(splitFile[1]);
    BigFraction c2A = stringToBF(splitFile[2]);
    ConditionalTwoCoinChannel CTCCA = new ConditionalTwoCoinChannel(conditionA, new TwoCoinChannel(c1A, c2A));

    BigFraction conditionB = stringToBF(splitFile[3]);
    BigFraction c1B = stringToBF(splitFile[4]);
    BigFraction c2B = stringToBF(splitFile[5]);
    ConditionalTwoCoinChannel CTCCB = new ConditionalTwoCoinChannel(conditionB, new TwoCoinChannel(c1B, c2B));

    List<ConditionalTwoCoinChannel> outputList = new ArrayList<ConditionalTwoCoinChannel>();

    outputList.add(CTCCA);
    outputList.add(CTCCB);

    return outputList;
```

and my two helper methods

```
private static String fileToString(String file)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String fileLine = fileReader.readLine();

        try {
            while (fileLine != null) {
                sBuilder.append(fileLine);
                sBuilder.append(" ");
                fileLine = fileReader.readLine();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("file not found");
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Input Error");
        }
        finally {
            fileReader.close();
        }


        return sBuilder.toString();




private static BigFraction stringToBF(String str){

            if (strToInt(str) == 0) {
                return BigFraction.ZERO;
            }
            else {
                String[] strSplit = str.split("(.*)a(.*)");
                int numerator = strToInt(strSplit[0]);
                int denominator = strToInt(strSplit[1]);
                return new BigFraction(numerator, denominator);             
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide your complete code with the classes so that debugging can be done.

Comment: how do i upload all of it?
The complete code i can do, but there are 9 class files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
String[] strSplit = str.split("(.*)a(.*)");
```

cannot split "1/2"

try

```
String[] strSplit = str.split("/");
```

Comment: I've changed it to that and its still giving me a NumberFormatException with "1/2". I also deleted the replaceall function so it should just try to split on the /

Comment: I think its here strToInt(str), try if (str.equals("0")) return BigFraction.ZERO; instead

Comment: omg, Evgeniy Dorofeev, you have same my life. thank you so much